# Edit large excel file with Python

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have a pretty complex excel file that includes pivot tables and sizes about 70 MB, and what I need is to edit one single cell with a script in Python. I'm trying openpyxl.

The problem is that it runs out of memory with no more than opening the file. Do you see any way around?

Comment: Currently no. Memory use will be around 4 GB for that file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [`pandas.read_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html). It may be better optimized for your purpose (reading one cell from one sheet).

Comment: Works with a script but in jupyter it runs out of memory too. Close enough for me.